# plotting points from matrix on matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector, matrix, plot

I have a matrix which shows me the posiions of a knight in a knights tour. I'm looking to find a way of firstly finding the numbers in order and outputting their positions e.g. on a smaller board X

```
X=[1 3; 4 2]
```

OUTPUT

```
A=[1 2 3 4]

b= [1 1; 2 4; 1 2; 1 3]
```

Something like this where b is the position of the values of A in the matrix

the only way I can think about doing this is using a series function of `find (n)` where `n=1..64` and then concatenating results

I then want to use this information to create a plot of the moves with a line/vector plot but am having difficulty in working out how to do this also.

Thanks,
Tessa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` to identify the visited board coordinates, followed by sorting them according to the order of the moves.

```
%# find the visited coordinates
[rows,cols,moveNumber]=find(A);

%# find out how to reorder the positions so that
%# the moves are in the right order
[~,sortIdx] = sort(moveNumber);

%# plot the moves
figure
plot(rows(sortIdx),cols(sortIdx),'-o')
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318990/efficient-way-of-making-checkers-from-connected-components/12319576#12319576) to find out how to make a chess board for the background.

Comment: thats awesome! I shall do some fiddling with this now but its great to get a perfect basis. Thankyou very much!